# cltopinfo command output on AIX

Tags: aix

I am trying to figure out the `cltopinfo` command for hb cluster.

what is the sample output of below AIX command?

```
/usr/es/sbin/cluster/utilities/cltopinfo -i | grep hb
```

i am not aware about how the `cltopinfo -i` output is when grep with hb.

Comment: Have you check the man page, have you try to search in google? https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/powerha-aix/7.2?topic=commands-cltopinfo-command

Comment: Yes checked on google and man page as well it doest mention about HB disk(heart beat) which m looking for in grep "hb".

Comment: If you have it you will get it. If not....